# JQuery selector to match a dynamically loaded script tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, script-tag

I want to match any raw script in an Ajax downloaded document, so I tried

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var scr = $(data).find('script[type="text/javascript"]');
```

The call is returning sucess, but the selector is not returning a match i.e.
`'script[type="text/javascript"]'` has a length of 0.

The page being loaded (i.e. `data`) definitely contains a test script tag like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert("JS running");
        });
    </script>
```

What am I missing here? Is it the way JQuery parses raw HTML?

### Followup:

this also returns no matches:
`var scr = data.find('script');`

**Note: Looking at the contents of $(data) it appears the JQuery parser strips out any Javascript tags.**

Comment: @Samuel Liew: Question updated. That also returns no matches... The plot thickens. $.getScript() is I gather only useful for downloading JScript files. This code is embedded in a dynamically loaded form page so I need access to any script in the page. Thanks

Comment: one possible solution is to set `datatype: "text"`

Comment: otherwise, why don't to use `load()` instead of `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Arun P Johny: I believe `load` won't do a `post`, only a `get` (I am dynamically loading forms into panels and reconnecting the JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that $(htmlstring) strips any script tags from the HTML. That is a shame.

The solution I came up with is based on the regex in the answer to [How to get regex to match multiple script tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441463/how-to-get-regex-to-match-multiple-script-tags)

```
        var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
        var scripts = "";
        var match;
        while (match = re.exec(data)) {
            if (match[1] != "") {
                scripts += match[0];
            }
        }
        panel.append(scripts);
```

I concatenate any inline scripts and the script executes immediately upon being appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use regex here.
Use Javascript `.match`.

Also, the string you comparing `script[type="text/javascript"]` is different than the one in the var: `<script type="text/javascript">`.

You should use it like:

```
matched = data.match('<script .*</script>');
```

It will have what was matched.

Comment: What do you mean different? It is a standard JQuery selector where the tag is `script` and the type of the tag is equal to `text/javascript`.

Comment: oh sorry i misinterpreted it..i was in impression you just comparing them.

Comment: It's a JQuery question to do with JQuery selector. Thanks anyway. Your example regex (regex might be a fallback if I can't get the selector to work), would not match script contents, just the opening script tags.

Comment: +1 for suggesting regex, but I needed a more robust match. I have completely the puzzle in my own answer. Thanks