# How can I make regex ignore content inbetween sets of HTML tags?

Tags: html, regex

In this situation:

```
<script>
function();
</script>

please don't touch me.

<script>
function();
</script>
```

I am trying to capture the tags and the information between them, but not the "please don't touch me in the middle". So far I have come up with this:

```
/<script>[^]+<\/script>/ig
```

Which captures everything from the very first `<script>` tag to the very last `</script>` tag.

Comment: Generally parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the regex not greedy, since it's greedy by default:

```
<script>[^]+?<\/script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `?` quantifier to match the first closing tag:

```
/<script>([^]*?)<\/script>/ig
```

But as others have already said, you would do best to use an XML parser when dealing with HTML.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, although i used `/<script>([^]*?)<\/script>/ig` instead so it would work over line breaks. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try below one regex

```
var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
```

Reference of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448870/5391322

I hope this will help you. Feel free to comment.