# Jquery: How to find phone number text and append image after phone number text

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to find phone numbers on page and append image after phone number.

I have did this way

```
 $("body:first").each(function(){
 // Create a REGEX Expression to detetc a phone number
 var regex =/\+\d{0,3}[-.\s]?\(?\d?\)?[-.\s]?\s?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}[-.\s]?\d{5}/g;
 var text = $(this).html();
text = text.match(regex).after('<img src="https://callhippo.com/dist/img/favicon_callhippo.png"/>');
$("body:first").html(text);
});
```

Comment: You didn't mention errors thrown... `text.match(regex).after()` would certainly throw one. See [ask]

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441463/how-to-get-regex-to-match-multiple-script-tags

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach:

```js
const regex = /(\+\d{0,3}[-.\s]?\(?\d?\)?[-.\s]?\s?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}[-.\s]?\d{5})/g;
const str = `abcd +8801917308239 pqrs hijk`;
const subst = `$1 <img src="https://callhippo.com/dist/img/favicon_callhippo.png"/>`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: an explanation why OP's approach doesn't work would help

Comment: This produce result :   <li class="contact"><a href="tel:$1 &lt;img src=" https:="" callhippo.com="" dist="" img="" favicon_callhippo.png"=""></a>"&gt;<i class="fa fa-phone-square fa-lg"></i> $1 <img src="https://callhippo.com/dist/img/favicon_callhippo.png"></li>

Answer (score 0):

The following code has the desired behavior other than the regex match failing. Your code failed because you didn't read the documentation of any of your functions. `.each()` iterates over all matching elements. `body` should only be in your document once so you wouldn't need `:first`. Instead iterate over `p` or whatever has text in it. Next `.after()` is supposed to insert a DOM (or whatever is in it) after another DOM. You asked it to insert a dom after an array of strings. That's why you get an undefined error calling .after(). Now if there is no match, the `match()` will give you null, so you need to make sure it's not null before doing anything else. I had it replace the lines with phone numbers in them to just phone numbers.

Of course, `match()` still throws null, so right now the code won't make the replacement, but that's due to the text in the dom not matching the regex.

```js
$("body p").each(function(){
 // Create a REGEX Expression to detetc a phone number
 re = /^.+/ //placeholder for correct regex expression
 var text = $(this).html();
 var nums = re.exec(text); //this doesn't match because of your regex
 if(nums != null){
    $(this).after('<img src="https://callhippo.com/dist/img/favicon_callhippo.png"/>');
 
    //$(this).html(nums.implode(",")); would replace the line with all the phone numbers
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>My number is 555-555-5555</p>
    <p>111-111-1111 is a cool phone number</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is not necessary text would be in p tag only, I am developing this tool globally web pages, like skype shows their icon after each phone number

Comment: Best practice would be to have a class for the type of DOM you expect to find so you can use the `.each()` over all of those. In general, if you changed it to `body` it would loop over the rest of the html markup.

Comment: $("body").each(function(){
 var regex =/\+\d{0,3}[-.\s]?\(?\d?\)?[-.\s]?\s?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}[-.\s]?\d{5}/g;
 var text = $(this).html();
     var nums = text.match(regex); //this doesn't match because of your regex
      if(nums != null){
           console.log("hello");
               $(this).after('<img src="https://callhippo.com/dist/img/favicon_callhippo.png"/>');

      }
});

Comment: did this way but no result

Comment: oh, it append after body end

Comment: please use \` symbols whenever you type code. Like I mentioned, your regex doesn't return any matches from the phone numbers, which is why that needs to be fixed as well. I'm not a regex expert so I figured I'd explain the rest of the errors (mainly the usage of `.after()` ) and mention the issue with regex

Comment: @Smith01 that's not appending at the end, that is the JS console of the snippet, I was having it log that the string existed so it would be clear to you that everything up to that point functioned, and it also demonstrates how `each()` works

Comment: @Smith01 I can't figure out the regex to your code so I put the find anything regex expression, but if `match` or `exec` could find matches that are phone numbers then it would work. Consider opening a question about why your regex expression doesn't find any matches